# I don't know what substitution should use in this integral

Tags: calculus

I have a problem with solving this integral.

$\int e^{(t-1)t}tdt$

Whatever I tried wont work. Please advice.

Comment: That integral does not have a nice closed form solution. Wolfram Alpha offers one involving the error function: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=INTEGRATE+e%5E((t%E2%88%921)t)+t+dt

Answer (score 0):

Hint: define $$u=t-{1\over 2}$$ and split the integral by two. Note that this integral has no closed form and you have to use the definition of [Q-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function).